# How to find the restrictions in differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[General solution and the assumptions made on C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7n7r.png)

At the moment, I am learning how to deduce the correct domain for the general solution after the ODE has been solved. I can solve for ODEs but really do not understand how the domains are worked out, especially in this example (please see the link above).

Can someone explain this in a simpler way? I have tried looking up in the books about this but this is not mentioned much. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

As the denominator is not defined at $t=0$ and $t=-\frac{1}{c}$, these points of discontinuity have to be excluded from the domain in which the solution is valid.